# How to use setOnClickListener what to put in View v for a preset method?

Tags: java, android

Alright so I'm trying to have dynamic buttons setup up, I've got the dynamic imaging to be setup through a switch and I'm trying to figure out what I need to put in the (View v) field of setting a specific method, below is the parts of my code that will be using this function:

This is the method that I use to set the image resource to the imageview on the current   activity: (i removed case 2+ etc as its the same code with different resource)

```
public void setActivity(ImageView activityNum, int activity) {
     switch (activity) {
         case 1: 
             activityNum.setImageResource(R.drawable.hello);
             activityNum.setOnClickListener(Hello(View v));
             break;
         case 2: etc...
     }
}
```

This is the method which plays the sound I have set, as it is just now in the xml code if i have " android:onClick="Hello" " this method works fine, but I am trying to figure out how to set the previous method where it is required and not just static. I assume I need to put the current activity in which would be activity_wednesday however I am not sure how to implement this.

```
public void Hello(View v) {
    player12 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hello);
    player12.start();
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. Can you clarify *exactly what* your problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue here is the way you set onClick listener to the ImageView is wrong .

setOnClickListener will register a callback to be invoked when this view is clicked and handle the onClick to invoke your method to play the media.

You need to change the code as below.

```
 public void setActivity(ImageView activityNum, int activity) {
    switch (activity) {
        case 1:
            activityNum.setImageResource(R.drawable.hello);
            activityNum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // handle the click here
                    Hello(v);
                }
            });
            break;
        case 2: etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error as follows: Cannot refer to a non-final variable activityNum inside an inner class defined in a different method, activityNum is a reference to a resource this is what I am passing into the method:

ImageView Wed1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.wednesday1);

So I am calling setActivity(Wed1, X);  Where X is just a number for the case it is being set too.

Comment: set ImageView activityNum as final

Comment: You should explain the code you post when answering. It makes the answer much more valuable.

Comment: It does make sense. You have posted a code-only answer and not explained anything. Explanations are much more valuable than code.

Comment: Libin, instead of using a `final`, you can just do it with `Hello(v)` because here, `v == activityNum`

Comment: Hum.. I disagree with you, Libin, downvote means: *"This answer is not useful"* (not wrong). Just rollover on it, you will see this message..

Comment: Libin, no that is not necessarily what it means. Anyway, add some explanations to your answers. It benefits you, the OP, and future visitors

Comment: If i make it a final does that not mean once it gets set it cannot change?

Comment: Libin, much better! And now you got an upvote. See, I'm not just a jerk but trying to help ;)  @Amgpewqq if this fixed your problem please accept it by clicking the check mark next to the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
public void setActivity(ImageView activityNum, int activity) {
  switch (activity) {
    case 1:
        activityNum.setImageResource(R.drawable.hello);
        activityNum.setOnClickListener(this);
```

then in your `Activity` create the method

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    // some code
}
```

and you need to add `implements OnClickListener()` to your `Activity` class definition. Ex.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener()
```

this is telling it to use the `onClick()` method implemented by the `OnClickListener` from your class definition. This will allow you to set it this same way on any of the `View`s in that method that need to call this same method and will pass the `ImageView` clicked to the `onClick()` functions `View` parameter.

if you want it to call that same method then inside the `onClick()` you can just call that method

```
 public void onClick(View v)
{
    Hello(v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

another way that i think it's the best for many times:

add a private member in your class like this:

```
private OnClickListner mOnClickListener = new OnClickListener(View view) {
};

public void setActivity(ImageView activityNum, int activity) {
   switch (activity) {
      case 1:
         activityNum.setImageResource(R.drawable.hello);
         activityNum.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
```

for other solution that is written here, you should note that:

1. if you implement an onclicklistener inline your code, you probably make some duplicate code every where you need a listener;
2. if your activity implement onclicklistener you make it visible for outside as onclicklistener. so every others even from outside of your activity can route their clicks to your activity